# Youtube videos are not streamed on Lightbox2 on Safari

Tags: javascript, media

I have a strange problem, which I don't know how to solve as it looks like nothing I can do about it... I am using Lightbox2 to play videos on my website and it's working perfectly if I watch Youtube videos on Ubuntu (Chrome, Mozilla, Safari, Opera) and Windows (Chrome, Mozilla, IE 7,8,9, Opera, Safari) but not on Safari in OS X. - it just go white screen and sometimes (very rarely) the video loads, but most of the time it doesn't.

The link of embeded video example is here: http://www.scanorama.lt/lt/mirties-signalas

do you have any idea, what could be the problem?

And sorry if it's not Drupal issue (then could you please direct me to the right source of info).

thanks

Comment: Seems like JavaScript issue. Try to find if people have same problem with Lightbox module.

Comment: Actually I have found a comment in another forum that it is about Caching and to solve this one need to change module's (lightbox2 in this particular case) weight in config tables. Can someone please explain me how to do that, as I am absolutely lost while trying to understand how to work with Hooks - maybe I can do that manualy in a database?